# Proper Use of Eval() in PHP

Tags: php, eval

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What situations demand the use of eval() because there are no alternatives?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336191/what-situations-demand-the-use-of-eval-because-there-are-no-alternatives)

I've never used it. But I'm trying to build a case for/against it. When can legitimately be used because there is no better alternative. If you use eval() what do you do to use input?

Comment: Why the -1? This is a legitimate question. It's just a duplicate. +1 to even it out

Comment: @Pekka: the only reason I can think of right now (which is not *my* reason though) is that questions with -5 score and below disappear from the front page.

Comment: @stereofrog then why not discuss it in the already existing duplicate?